# Django REST framework - 3 models related to one another, DELETE request fails

Tags: python, django, python-3.x, django-rest-framework, django-views

I have an issue with deleting an instance of a model (let's call it A) which has an instance of another model (B) related to A by Foreign Key constraint, and fails to delete. It's using CASCADE parameter, however I get response 500 which in the tracebacks just says that the server has crashed/database went into recovery mode.

The following is my code:

**views.py**

```
class TaskInstance(generics.RetrieveUpdateDestroyAPIView):
    """
    Returns Task instance
    """
    queryset = Task.objects.all()
    serializer_class = TaskSerializer

class StepList(generics.ListCreateAPIView):
    """
    List all Steps (OR for specified task), or create a new one
    """
    queryset = Step.objects.all()
    serializer_class = StepSerializer
    filter_fields = ('task',)
```

**models.py**

```
class Category(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=25, blank=False)

    class Meta:
        ordering = ('id',)


class Task(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=25, blank=False)
    cat = models.ForeignKey(Category, related_name='tasks', on_delete=models.CASCADE)

    class Meta:
        ordering = ('id',)


class Step(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=25, blank=False)
    completed = models.BooleanField(blank=True, default=False)
    task = models.ForeignKey(Task, related_name='steps', on_delete=models.CASCADE)

    class Meta:
        ordering = ('id',)
```

**serializers.py**

```
class CategorySerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    tasks = serializers.PrimaryKeyRelatedField(many=True, read_only=True)
    class Meta:
        model = Category
        fields = ('id', 'name', 'tasks')


class TaskSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    steps = serializers.PrimaryKeyRelatedField(many=True, read_only=True)
    class Meta:
        model = Task
        fields = ('id', 'name', 'steps')


class StepSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    task = serializers.PrimaryKeyRelatedField(queryset=Task.objects.all(), many=False)
    class Meta:
        model = Step
        fields = ('id', 'name', 'completed')
```

**My perfect scenario:** I'd like to be able to send a DELETE request for specific Task model, which deletes every Step model that relates to it.

I'd appreciate any help!

**Traceback**

```
OperationalError at /task/1/
server closed the connection unexpectedly
    This probably means the server terminated abnormally
    before or while processing the request.


Request Method: DELETE
Request URL: http://localhost:7000/task/1/
Django Version: 2.1.3
Python Executable: C:\Users\vaida\Documents\Coding\android-tm-api\venv\Scripts\python.exe
Python Version: 3.7.1
Python Path: ['C:\\Users\\vaida\\Documents\\Coding\\android-tm-api\\android_tm_api', 'C:\\Users\\vaida\\Documents\\Coding\\android-tm-api\\venv\\Scripts\\python37.zip', 'C:\\Users\\vaida\\Documents\\Coding\\android-tm-api\\venv\\DLLs', 'C:\\Users\\vaida\\Documents\\Coding\\android-tm-api\\venv\\lib', 'C:\\Users\\vaida\\Documents\\Coding\\android-tm-api\\venv\\Scripts', 'c:\\users\\vaida\\appdata\\local\\programs\\python\\python37\\Lib', 'c:\\users\\vaida\\appdata\\local\\programs\\python\\python37\\DLLs', 'C:\\Users\\vaida\\Documents\\Coding\\android-tm-api\\venv', 'C:\\Users\\vaida\\Documents\\Coding\\android-tm-api\\venv\\lib\\site-packages']
Server time: Fri, 16 Nov 2018 20:05:14 +0000
Installed Applications:
['django.contrib.admin',
 'django.contrib.auth',
 'django.contrib.contenttypes',
 'django.contrib.sessions',
 'django.contrib.messages',
 'django.contrib.staticfiles',
 'rest_framework',
 'api.apps.ApiConfig',
 'django_filters']
Installed Middleware:
['django.middleware.security.SecurityMiddleware',
 'django.contrib.sessions.middleware.SessionMiddleware',
 'django.middleware.common.CommonMiddleware',
 'django.middleware.csrf.CsrfViewMiddleware',
 'django.contrib.auth.middleware.AuthenticationMiddleware',
 'django.contrib.messages.middleware.MessageMiddleware',
 'django.middleware.clickjacking.XFrameOptionsMiddleware']


Traceback:

File "C:\Users\vaida\Documents\Coding\android-tm-api\venv\lib\site-packages\django\db\backends\base\base.py" in _commit
  239.                 return self.connection.commit()

The above exception (server closed the connection unexpectedly
    This probably means the server terminated abnormally
    before or while processing the request.
) was the direct cause of the following exception:

File "C:\Users\vaida\Documents\Coding\android-tm-api\venv\lib\site-packages\django\db\transaction.py" in __exit__
  212.                         connection.commit()

File "C:\Users\vaida\Documents\Coding\android-tm-api\venv\lib\site-packages\django\db\backends\base\base.py" in commit
  261.         self._commit()

File "C:\Users\vaida\Documents\Coding\android-tm-api\venv\lib\site-packages\django\db\backends\base\base.py" in _commit
  239.                 return self.connection.commit()

File "C:\Users\vaida\Documents\Coding\android-tm-api\venv\lib\site-packages\django\db\utils.py" in __exit__
  89.                 raise dj_exc_value.with_traceback(traceback) from exc_value

File "C:\Users\vaida\Documents\Coding\android-tm-api\venv\lib\site-packages\django\db\backends\base\base.py" in _commit
  239.                 return self.connection.commit()

During handling of the above exception (server closed the connection unexpectedly
    This probably means the server terminated abnormally
    before or while processing the request.
), another exception occurred:

File "C:\Users\vaida\Documents\Coding\android-tm-api\venv\lib\site-packages\django\db\backends\base\base.py" in ensure_connection
  216.                 self.connect()

File "C:\Users\vaida\Documents\Coding\android-tm-api\venv\lib\site-packages\django\db\backends\base\base.py" in connect
  194.         self.connection = self.get_new_connection(conn_params)

File "C:\Users\vaida\Documents\Coding\android-tm-api\venv\lib\site-packages\django\db\backends\postgresql\base.py" in get_new_connection
  178.         connection = Database.connect(**conn_params)

File "C:\Users\vaida\Documents\Coding\android-tm-api\venv\lib\site-packages\psycopg2\__init__.py" in connect
  130.     conn = _connect(dsn, connection_factory=connection_factory, **kwasync)

The above exception (server closed the connection unexpectedly
    This probably means the server terminated abnormally
    before or while processing the request.
) was the direct cause of the following exception:

File "C:\Users\vaida\Documents\Coding\android-tm-api\venv\lib\site-packages\django\core\handlers\exception.py" in inner
  34.             response = get_response(request)

File "C:\Users\vaida\Documents\Coding\android-tm-api\venv\lib\site-packages\django\core\handlers\base.py" in _get_response
  126.                 response = self.process_exception_by_middleware(e, request)

File "C:\Users\vaida\Documents\Coding\android-tm-api\venv\lib\site-packages\django\core\handlers\base.py" in _get_response
  124.                 response = wrapped_callback(request, *callback_args, **callback_kwargs)

File "C:\Users\vaida\Documents\Coding\android-tm-api\venv\lib\site-packages\django\views\decorators\csrf.py" in wrapped_view
  54.         return view_func(*args, **kwargs)

File "C:\Users\vaida\Documents\Coding\android-tm-api\venv\lib\site-packages\django\views\generic\base.py" in view
  68.             return self.dispatch(request, *args, **kwargs)

File "C:\Users\vaida\Documents\Coding\android-tm-api\venv\lib\site-packages\rest_framework\views.py" in dispatch
  495.             response = self.handle_exception(exc)

File "C:\Users\vaida\Documents\Coding\android-tm-api\venv\lib\site-packages\rest_framework\views.py" in handle_exception
  455.             self.raise_uncaught_exception(exc)

File "C:\Users\vaida\Documents\Coding\android-tm-api\venv\lib\site-packages\rest_framework\views.py" in dispatch
  492.             response = handler(request, *args, **kwargs)

File "C:\Users\vaida\Documents\Coding\android-tm-api\venv\lib\site-packages\rest_framework\generics.py" in delete
  293.         return self.destroy(request, *args, **kwargs)

File "C:\Users\vaida\Documents\Coding\android-tm-api\venv\lib\site-packages\rest_framework\mixins.py" in destroy
  93.         self.perform_destroy(instance)

File "C:\Users\vaida\Documents\Coding\android-tm-api\venv\lib\site-packages\rest_framework\mixins.py" in perform_destroy
  97.         instance.delete()

File "C:\Users\vaida\Documents\Coding\android-tm-api\venv\lib\site-packages\django\db\models\base.py" in delete
  880.         return collector.delete()

File "C:\Users\vaida\Documents\Coding\android-tm-api\venv\lib\site-packages\django\db\models\deletion.py" in delete
  306.                             sender=model, instance=obj, using=self.using

File "C:\Users\vaida\Documents\Coding\android-tm-api\venv\lib\site-packages\django\db\transaction.py" in __exit__
  256.                     connection.set_autocommit(True)

File "C:\Users\vaida\Documents\Coding\android-tm-api\venv\lib\site-packages\django\db\backends\base\base.py" in set_autocommit
  394.         self.ensure_connection()

File "C:\Users\vaida\Documents\Coding\android-tm-api\venv\lib\site-packages\django\db\backends\base\base.py" in ensure_connection
  216.                 self.connect()

File "C:\Users\vaida\Documents\Coding\android-tm-api\venv\lib\site-packages\django\db\utils.py" in __exit__
  89.                 raise dj_exc_value.with_traceback(traceback) from exc_value

File "C:\Users\vaida\Documents\Coding\android-tm-api\venv\lib\site-packages\django\db\backends\base\base.py" in ensure_connection
  216.                 self.connect()

File "C:\Users\vaida\Documents\Coding\android-tm-api\venv\lib\site-packages\django\db\backends\base\base.py" in connect
  194.         self.connection = self.get_new_connection(conn_params)

File "C:\Users\vaida\Documents\Coding\android-tm-api\venv\lib\site-packages\django\db\backends\postgresql\base.py" in get_new_connection
  178.         connection = Database.connect(**conn_params)

File "C:\Users\vaida\Documents\Coding\android-tm-api\venv\lib\site-packages\psycopg2\__init__.py" in connect
  130.     conn = _connect(dsn, connection_factory=connection_factory, **kwasync)

Exception Type: OperationalError at /task/1/
Exception Value: server closed the connection unexpectedly
    This probably means the server terminated abnormally
    before or while processing the request.
```

Comment: _tracebacks just says that the server has crashed/database went into recovery mode_ Can you post the full error message?

Comment: I've added the traceback to the original post

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After a while I figured out that I was approaching the problem the wrong way... It wasn't the code's fault - it works fine. The problem was to do with database set up through pgAdmin. Once dropped and Django project re-migrated, everything seems to work fine.